# Size of the text box changes when click on a link button

Tags: html, asp.net, user-interface, textbox

I have a textbox which diplays a description. Everything works fine. There is another link button to view a pdf. But **when i click on the link button, size of the textbox reduce**. But i dont want it change its size. How can i avoid it happening?

Here is my code

```html
<div id="div8" style="width: 95%; height: auto; float: left;">
  <div id="div41" runat="server" style="width: auto; float: left">
    <asp:Label ID="div411" Text="Remarks :" runat="server" Style="float: left; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 70px">
    </asp:Label>
   </div>
   <div id="div42" runat="server" style="width: 60%; height: 15%">
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtAreaRemarks" TextMode="multiline" Columns="20" Rows="10" runat="server" Style="margin-top: 5px; width: 87%; height: 80%; margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px" ReadOnly="true" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is that link button.

Comment: Please provide complete code.

Comment: is the  link button in a separate div - in the above code -- where is the link button.. share the code pls..

Comment: Thanks for asking, but i managed it. I gave them fixed sizes. now it doesn't make any problems.